# CIL level debugger for C# code on Linux with mono

Tags: c#, linux, debugging, mono, cil

I have the following C# code I've compiled on Linux with mono,
and I want to single step its CIL commands. Specifically,
I want to be able to examine the stack,
and see values pushed and popped from it.

```
using System;
namespace ARITH
{
    class MUL
    {
        static void Main() 
        {
            int i = 742;
            int j = 999;

            if (i*j == 15242)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("MMMM");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I single step the generated CIL code inside main?
Here is the generated CIL of the main function:

```
$ mcs main.cs
$ monodis main.exe > main.cil
$ sed -n '37,60p;61q' main.cil
    .method private static hidebysig 
           default void Main ()  cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2058
        .entrypoint
        // Code size 36 (0x24)
        .maxstack 2
        .locals init (
            int32   V_0,
            int32   V_1)
        IL_0000:  ldc.i4 742
        IL_0005:  stloc.0 
        IL_0006:  ldc.i4 999
        IL_000b:  stloc.1 
        IL_000c:  ldloc.0 
        IL_000d:  ldloc.1 
        IL_000e:  mul 
        IL_000f:  ldc.i4 15242
        IL_0014:  bne.un IL_0023

        IL_0019:  ldstr "MMMM"
        IL_001e:  call void class [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        IL_0023:  ret 
    } // end of method MUL::Main
```

EDIT:

After `sudo apt install sdb`, I prepared a simple script to make sure
I got the commands right, and indeed the following script prints correct values for local variables `i` and `j`:

```
$ cat sdbCommands.txt
bp add func ARITH.MUL.Main
r main.exe
step
step
step
step
print i
print j
$ sdb -f sdbCommands.txt
```

However, I still can't find the equivalent of gdb's `stepi`. That is, to step in the CIL level ...

Comment: There are a lot of options on Windows (deblector, ReflectorPro, WinDdg/Sos, etc..), but the closest you can get on Linux would be Mono's soft debugger, otherwise native debugging via GDB/LLDB.

Comment: @SushiHangover could you please write a short answer for using mono's soft debugger? or gdb?

Comment: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/docs/soft-debugger/ & here - https://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/debug/debugger/

Comment: `mono --debug program.exe`

Comment: There's also the SDB client - https://github.com/mono/sdb.

Comment: @slm when I write `mono --debug main.exe` nothing happens

Comment: You have to compile it so that it can be debugged w/ specific switches. `-debug`. Otherwise symbols are not present in the binary for the debugger.

Comment: still no go, even if I do `mcs -debug main.cs` ... then `mono --debug main.exe`

Comment: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/docs/soft-debugger/ and usage: https://github.com/mono/sdb

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I've installed `sdb` and managed to set breakpoints and single step C# instructions ... still haven't managed to single step CIL commands though ...